# Regular Expression Match string after n lines only if another string before n lines matches in any Text Editor supporting PCRE

Tags: regex, find, pcre, text-editor, regex-look-ahead

I have a PHP Database configuration file(opened in Code Editor supporting PCRE) which contains various engine's credentials for generating connection strings.

Now as I mentioned in the question title, I want to match certain string "DB_DATABASE", only if before n lines(let's say 3) there's presence of 'mysql' like below:

```
....
....
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'anydb'),
....
....
```

If I say before 3 lines then it should not match the "mysql" before 4 lines i.e. it should not match `'mysql' => [`. Note that there are other DB engine connetion details besides the one mentioned here, so need to match mysql and only when it is present exactly 3 lines above `DB_DATABASE`.

I tried some complex regexes but none gives me what I want, let me mention one which I thought was atleast close, but in vain:

```
^[\S\s]*?mysql\S*$(?:\n.*){3}\S*DB_DATABASE
```

Appreciate anyone putting efforts to help resolve this...

Comment: Is this what you looking for? `(?=.*mysql(?:.*\n){4}.*(DB_DATABASE))` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/u86ZaR/1

Comment: Yes this works good, thank you !! But one thing though, this matches the whole section match, I only want the word DB_DATABASE to be matched, is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest matching the words as whole words and use the `\K` operator to only consume the `DB_DATABASE` string:

```
\bmysql\b.*(?:\n.*){3}\n.*\K\bDB_DATABASE\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SE51kS/3/). *Details*:

- `\bmysql\b` - a whole word `mysql`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\n.*){3}` - three lines
- `\n` - a newline
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator that removes the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `\bDB_DATABASE\b` - a whole word `DB_DATABASE`.

**NOTE**: If your line endings are mixed or unknown, you should replace all occurrences of `\n` with `\R` in the pattern (`\R` matches any line ending sequence).

Comment: Very nice, descriptive and info-loaded answer, thanks a lot !!